# Inventory Management solution integrated with Magento

Tags: inventory

What solution do you guys use/recommend for Inventory Management:

- Purchase Orders
- Receive Goods (GRN)
- Track Stock movements (multiple locations, transfers, consumption)
- Ship Goods (Delivery Note)
- Reports (stock available on-hand, reserved, stock value, etc)
- integrated with Magento

So far, some customers use the ERP system (Microsoft Dynamics AX/NAV, SAP, Netsuite, local ERP systems, etc) for Inventory Management, but I am looking for a solution that handles only the inventory part and updates Inventory field in Magento, allowing traceability for stock items.
I have so far on the list [boostmyshop](http://www.boostmyshop.com/)  but I'm not happy with what they have in there and how they developed that as a magento "module".

Comment: Given that Magento cannot natively do much of what you need (and isn't really designed for that purpose). You are better off with a separate ERP system. As to which is the most appropriate - only you will know. NB. Shopping questions aren't allowed on SE .

Comment: @sonassi Yoav announced a new start-up he is involved in: Oro CRM (http://www.orocrm.com/)... Starting from that I was wondering if there is something similar for Inventory Management. I've shared what I also encountered so far. I couldn't find on meta a discussion about this kind of questions, can you point that to me?

Comment: Shopping questions have always been frowned upon. Have a read of [this article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: @sonassi flag the question if you believe it's a "shopping question".

Comment: I've upvoted this because I really want some ideas as well.  Screw the shopping policy :-)

Answer (score 2):

While looking for a solution that does what you describe I found http://unleashedsoftware.com/.

Here is how each of your required features are covered in Unleashed:

- Purchase Orders - Purchasing is a primary feature of the application
- Receive Goods (GRN) - In Unleashed, receiving is an action you perform on a particular PO.
- Track Stock movements (multiple locations, transfers, consumption) - All this and more is supported
- Ship Goods (Delivery Note) - As with receive goods, this is folded in with invoice management
- Reports (stock available on-hand, reserved, stock value, etc) - All these reports and more are available
- Integrated with Magento - Yes

Basically, Unleashed looks to be exactly what you need!

The only reason I'm not listing other apps is from my research there aren't really any cloud-based inventory management apps that are nearly as good...either too many features or not enough.

Answer (score 1):

We made this module long time ago. Its a Stock and purchase order management module. It handles alot of processes related to stock management and purchase orders and automatically keeps track of your orders, so the orders ready for shipping will show in a dedicated grid.

http://www.typoart.dk/en/magento-moduler/typoart-magento-supply-order-management.html